# why is it desirable to have fewer explanatory variables in the second stage of a Heckman test?

Tags: regression, feature-selection, sample-size, heckman

My old lecturer recommended that the second stage of a henchman test should preferably contain at least one fewer explanatory variables than the first (selection) stage. what is the precise reasoning behind this and does it matter when the variable list is relatively large (17 explanatory variables)? thanks!